# Return Promise after job execution in Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, node-schedule

I´m creating a small Node.js application for some monitoring stuff. The following operation has to be made with this app:

A job scheduler (using **node-schedule** module) is retrieving data from a web service within a time period and inserting the content into an array (for further processing). **After** finishing the job a promise should resolve the complete array in order to use it in my main program.

Here is my coding so far. With this coding the promise gets resolved before finishing the job and the array is empty. Can you give me any hints how to solve this?

```
async function dataRetrieval(start, end, rule){
   let array = [];
   return new Promise(function (resolve) {
       schedule.scheduleJob({start: start, end: end, rule: rule}, async function (){
           let data = await service.getData();
           array.push(data);
       });
       resolve(array);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `scheduleJob` is an asynchronous function, and your `resolve` call takes place outside of your callback, before the job is finished.

You can use the `fireDate` value that is passed to the callback from `scheduleJob` to check if the current execution is the last one. If so, only then, you call `resolve` with the final data from the callback:

```
async function dataRetrieval(start, end, rule){
   let array = [];
   return new Promise(function (resolve) {
       schedule.scheduleJob({start: start, end: end, rule: rule}, async function (fireDate) {
           let data = await service.getData();
           array.push(data);

           if (fireDate >= end) {
               resolve(array);  
           }
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was the hint and after some modification I´ve got it working! Thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are resolving it outside the callback completion. You need to resolve it inside the callback.

Something like this

```
async function dataRetrieval(start, end, rule){
    let array = [];
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        schedule.scheduleJob({start: start, end: end, rule: rule}, async function (){
            let data = await service.getData();
            array.push(data);
            resolve(array);
        });
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint too! Actually the answer above suits better for me, but thank you for your effort and time!